# How to create a new Google Sites under a secondary domain in the same G Suite account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-sites

I am a G Suite user.  When I create a site in the New Google Sites, the URL looks like the following, where `foosite` is the site's name, and `foo.com` is the primary domain associated with my G Suite account:

```
https:/ /sites.google.com/foo.com/foosite
```

I want to create a new site using one of the secondary domains associated with the G Suite account, and I want the secondary domain to be in the URL instead of the primary one.  For example, where `barsite` is a site's name, and `bar.com` is a secondary domain associated with my account:

```
https:/ /sites.google.com/bar.com/barsite
```

In the Classic version of Google Sites I had this option by selecting the domain to use in the URL.

I have tried creating a site while logged into an account whose username uses the secondary domain, such as `jdo@bar.com`, and which has no alias on the primary `foo.com` domain, but only the site name could be customized, and the URL would always include the primary domain. For example:

```
https:/ /sites.google.com/foo.com/barsite
```

How can I create a site such that the URL includes a secondary domain associated with my G Suite account instead of the primary one?

Comment: 2024' still i have found no solution to:
MY_Domain 1 - Site
MY_DOmain 2 - Site it only allows it under the primary domain...
not even a simple mask... crazy.... or did i miss something....tia

Answer (score 1):

At the moment all sites in "new" Google Sites are under the primary domain of the G Suite account. It is not possible to use it for a secondary domain.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

1. Temporarily change your primary G Suite or Google Workspace domain to the secondary domain.
2. Create the custom URL for the Google Site. This will now be created with your secondary domain (which is now primary).
3. Make the original domain primary again.

**Reasoning**
This new system is based on Google Sites automatically assigning the domain to the personalized URL, unlike what was done in Classic Google Sites which allowed you to choose between your domains.

**Note:** [Translated from the original post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/148298/1)

Comment: This solution is not working. I changed the primary domain weeks ago, still, when I create a new site Google is placing the new site under the old primary domain even if it is now a secondary domain.